# accessing environment variable in gocd pipeline for aws EMR add step

Tags: environment-variables, amazon-emr, go-cd

How to pass environment variable inside a gocd step as an argument . Here When I pass ${KAFKA_CODE}  it gives the error. and when I pass only $KAFKA_CODE, then command submitted as `aws s3 cp $KAFKA_CODE /home/hadoop/` on cluster. But I want this to be as `aws s3 cp s3://code_path/spark-jobs.zip /home/hadoop/` Please let me know how can this be fixed as I am new to gocd

```
format_version: 3
pipelines:
  copy_code_cluster:
    group: MyGroup
    materials:
      terraform_git:
        git: git@gitlab.xxxx.com/spark-jobs.git
        branch: develop

    environment_variables:
      KAFKA_CODE: "s3://code_path/spark-jobs.zip"

    stages:
    - provision:
        clean_workpace: true
        jobs:
          terraform:
            tasks:
              - exec:
                  command: /bin/sh
                  arguments:
                    - "-c"
                    - "aws emr add-steps --cluster-id 'j-xxxxxxx' --steps 'Name= \"copy zip  to cluster home directory\" , Jar=\"command-runner.jar\",Args=[ \"aws\" , \"s3\" , \"cp\", \"$KAFKA_CODE\" ,  \"/home/hadoop/\"]' "
```

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by using parameters instead of environment_variables. environment_variables as not accessed inside tasks. only parameters can be accessed.

```
format_version: 3
pipelines:
  copy_code_cluster:
    group: MyGroup
    materials:
      terraform_git:
        git: git@gitlab.xxxx.com/spark-jobs.git
        branch: develop

    parameters:
      KAFKA_CODE: "s3://code_path/spark-jobs.zip"

    stages:
    - provision:
        clean_workpace: true
        jobs:
          terraform:
            tasks:
              - exec:
                  command: /bin/sh
                  arguments:
                    - "-c"
                    - "aws emr add-steps --cluster-id 'j-xxxxxxx' --steps 'Name= \"copy zip  to cluster home directory\" , Jar=\"command-runner.jar\",Args=[ \"aws\" , \"s3\" , \"cp\", \"#{KAFKA_CODE}\" ,  \"/home/hadoop/\"]' "
```